# Drop columns with NA's in a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, na

Consider a large list of data frames called `GEER` where some of the columns contain only `NA`. In R, how can I remove all columns containg `NA` from all elements.

*Not all the elements have the items including `NA`s.

```
> GEER
$ ch_0  :'data.frame': 74 obs. of  6000 variables:
..$ TIME  : Factor w/ 527 levels "2020-01" "2020-03" "2020-04" ...
..$ NAME  : Factor w/ 100 levels "XTC_R" "DCC_S" "HG_CC" ...
..$ K_207  : num [1:100] 10.7 18.5 18.7 10.3 62.6 ...
..$ K_220  : num [1:100] 33.2 70.6 13.5 13.7 15.5 ...
..$ M_220  : num [1:100] 10.3 18.04 18.3 9.7 5.7 ...
..$ M_207  : num [1:100] 4.8 4.5 4.0 6.5 5.1 ...
$ ch_1290  :'data.frame':  380 obs. of  6000 variables:
..$ TIME  : Factor w/ 150 levels "2020-01" "2020-03" "2020-04" ...
..$ NAME  : Factor w/ 100 levels "KTC_D" "DSC_C" "KL_SC" ...
..$ K_507  : num [1:100] 10.7 18.5 18.7 10.3 12.6 ...
..$ K_444  : num [1:100] NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ M_513  : num [1:100] NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ M_102  : num [1:100] NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ K_505  : num [1:100] 14.0 18.3 14.7 11.2 12.6 ...
```

The desire output will be:

```
> GEER_out
$ ch_0  :'data.frame': 74 obs. of  6000 variables:
..$ TIME  : Factor w/ 527 levels "2020-01" "2020-03" "2020-04" ...
..$ NAME  : Factor w/ 100 levels "XTC_R" "DCC_S" "HG_CC" ...
..$ K_207  : num [1:100] 10.7 18.5 18.7 10.3 62.6 ...
..$ K_220  : num [1:100] 33.2 70.6 13.5 13.7 15.5 ...
..$ M_220  : num [1:100] 10.3 18.04 18.3 9.7 5.7 ...
..$ M_207  : num [1:100] 4.8 4.5 4.0 6.5 5.1 ...
$ ch_1290  :'data.frame':  380 obs. of  5997 variables:
..$ TIME  : Factor w/ 150 levels "2020-01" "2020-03" "2020-04" ...
..$ NAME  : Factor w/ 100 levels "KTC_D" "DSC_C" "KL_SC" ...
..$ K_507  : num [1:100] 10.7 18.5 18.7 10.3 12.6 ...
..$ K_505  : num [1:100] 14.0 18.3 14.7 11.2 12.6 ...
```

I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `remove_empty` from the package `janitor`:

```
library(janitor)

lapply(GEER, janitor::remove_empty, which = "cols")
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R` we can use `Filter` with `lapply`

```
lapply(GEER, function(dat) Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)), dat))
```